# Click to move code works in one scene but not the rest, NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, click, game-engine, move

This is my click to move code, This is my first question, so I'm new to this. If you need any more information I will be happy to give it to you!

I have made a top-down dungeon game (Like Diablo), I completed creating all of the dungeon levels and started to animate and move my player, I got it working starting on the third and last level and it works perfect, I was happy as this is my first time making a game. I created a prefab of the character and moved it into the other levels and only got error when I clicked to move, I have tried to add them in separately but still didn't work sadly.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ClickToMove : MonoBehaviour 
{
public float speed;
public CharacterController controller;
private Vector3 position;

public AnimationClip idle;
public AnimationClip run;


public static Vector3 cursorPosition;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    position = transform.position;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{

            if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                //Locate where the player clicked on the terrain
                locatePosition();
            }

            //Move the player to the position
            moveToPosition();
        }



void locatePosition()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000))
    {
        if(hit.collider.tag!="Player"&&hit.collider.tag!="Enemy")
        {
            position = hit.point;
        }
    }
}
void locateCursor()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000))
    {
        cursorPosition = hit.point;
    }
}





void moveToPosition()
{
    //Game Object is moving
    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, position)>1)
    {
        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(position-    transform.position, Vector3.forward);

        newRotation.x = 0f;
        newRotation.z = 0f;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,     newRotation, Time.deltaTime * 10);
        controller.SimpleMove(transform.forward * speed);

        GetComponent<Animation>().CrossFade("run");


    }
    //Game Object is not moving
    else
    {
        GetComponent<Animation>().CrossFade("idle");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I can't be sure what reference is not set but that is why you are getting the NullReferenceException error. If you click the exception in the unity output window, it should take you to the relevant line of code.

Answer (score 0):

As Catwood said, double clicking on the error in the console will take you to the relevant line of code that's causing the exception. I'd expect it to be one of the GetComponent calls though as you're trying to call the CrossFade function on something that might return null (in the case that the Animator component can't be found).

As a side note, you should avoid using GetComponent like this as it's inefficient. Instead, create a private / protected variable and store the reference when you first get the component.